# Fix IE10 < padding right on select tags

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to style select tags in a nice way, adding paddings all around.
Works wonderfully on all browsers, except IE.

This is what happens on IE (most of them, from version 10):

[image]

How can I fix that gap on the right?
Adding padding-right:0 is enough, but what's the best way to target all the IE browsers?
Is there a way to feature-detect the issue, or fix it with CSS in an universal way?

Comment: have u tried float:right

Comment: I should start by saying from a theoretical point of view that this is a bad idea.  Select tags can be rendered (theoretically) any way the browser so chooses, it doesn't even have to necessarily be a dropdown.  It could even be a list of radiobuttons.  How the user's browser decides to render it really is a user preference, not a web page designers choice.  Now, that said... Google is your friend, you'll find that there are solutions for it, but most have serious drawbacks to them. All of the major (non-mobile) browsers do render it as a drop down.  Mobiles often render it as a wheel control.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your HTML :

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css">
  #yourselect {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```